# Escape square brackets when assigning a class name to an element

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how to escape the square bracket character when setting a class name with jQuery?

Try the following:

```
$('#txtFirstname').addClass('test[someval]')
```

then

```
$('#txtFirstname').attr('class')
```

you'll see the class is there.

Now try

```
$('#txtFirstname').hasClass('test[someval]')
```

FAIL

The only reason I can think of is the square brackets.

And I need these for my jQuery validation you see.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Escape with TWO (2) backslashes.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: The two backslashes are only because of JavaScript string escaping. It's actually, correctly, a single backslash you are sending to jQuery itself.

Comment: For `<span id="foo[bar]" />` you can select with `$("#foo\\[bar\\]")` as discussed, or `$('[id="foo[bar]"]')` by using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: @Travis I don't think square brackets [] are valid in "id" for html versions prior to 5. They are valid in "name".

Comment: I've confirmed this works for apostropies also: `jQuery("#accommodations option[value='L\\'acquaviva 11/1/2010-11/8/2010']").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();` Thanks for the great tip!

Comment: I am not able to select (coincidentally a select tag) `<select name="foo[bar]">` using
`$('select[name=foo\\[bar\\]]')` however I _am_ able to do so using `$('select[name="foo[bar]"])`, see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute#answer-2365005

Comment: For the records, this was a jQuery bug that was fixed on 1.4. With later versions you don't need to escape metacharacters in class names when calling `.hasClass()`. See my answer for further details.

Comment: BTW, the FAQ entry talks about **selectors** and the `addClass()` function does not accept selectors. If you add two backslashes you'll add a bogus slash to the class name: [online demo](http://jsbin.com/ISemozUk/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: The FAQ item was renamed: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Answer (score 9):

The introduction of [jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) gives the above explanation about this:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Comment: That quote is from the **Selectors** category. A class name is not a selector. If prepend two backslashes you'll add a bogus slash to the class name: [proof](http://jsbin.com/ISemozUk/1/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 4):

If the selector is contained within a variable (or if you can get it into a variable), the code below may be helpful:

```
selector_name = $this.attr('class');
//e.g selector_name = users[0][first:name]

escaped_selector_name = selector_name.replace(/(:|\.|\[|\])/g,'\\$1');
//e.g escaped_selector_name = users\\[0\\]\\[first\\:name\\]
```

In short we prefix all special characters with double backslash. Here's some additional documentation from the jQuery site:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **you don't need to escape brackets** because the argument is a [class name](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), not a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). It didn't work for you because of a bug in earlier jQuery versions that has long been fixed.

To demonstrate it, here's your code running under different versions:

- jQuery/1.3.2 (buggy):

```js
$('#txtFirstname').addClass('test[someval]')
$('#txtFirstname').attr('class')
console.log($('#txtFirstname').hasClass('test[someval]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txtFirstname"></div>
```

- jQuery/1.4.0 (fixed):

```js
$('#txtFirstname').addClass('test[someval]')
$('#txtFirstname').attr('class')
console.log($('#txtFirstname').hasClass('test[someval]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txtFirstname"></div>
```

So the issued was apparently fixed on jQuery/1.4.0. I found [a ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4817) regarding this (though it's tagged as being fixed on 1.4.2 rather than 1.4.0).

I insist: the rule to quote or escape metacharacters with `\\` in order to use them as a literal part of a name only applies to [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). However, the [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method does not receive a selector as argument but as class name:

> ```
> .hasClass( className )
>
>     className
>     Type: String
>     The class name to search for.
> ```