# jQuery - select a element by the "name" attribute

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I know you can do this with `[name]` but the problem is that my input name attribute contains square brackets `[]` inside :(

```
var thename = 'blah[blah][]'; // <- this value is dynamic
$("*[name='"+thename+"']").each()...
```

Is there any other method I could select this element by the name field?

Comment: I remember that this situation is messy and remember people saying to avoid it

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)

Comment: You might as well add a class on the element. It would be faster to evaluate.

Comment: For future reference (this is intended to be helpful, not snarky): If you had included a more rigorous and exact summary of your question in the title, you very likely would have seen the exact duplicate question listed. This would have saved you the time of even writing your question, and jumped straight to the answer.

Comment: BTW, did you try this? My tests show that it just works, quoted or not, with the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: yes, and I get a 'undefined' object

Comment: actually you're right. the problem was elsewhere, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape them, you can do this with a regex replace

```
var thename = 'blah[blah][]'; // <- this value is dynamic
$("*[name='"+thename.replace(/\[/g, '\\\\[').replace(/\]/g, '\\\\]')+"']").each()...
```

Or to make a function

```
function esc(a) { return a.replace(/\[/g, '\\\\[').replace(/\]/g, '\\\\]'); }
var thename = 'blah[blah][]'; // <- this value is dynamic
$("*[name='"+esc(thename)+"']").each()...
```

Comment: you have to use double backslash.. :)

Comment: Thanks just wanted to keep you on your toes

Comment: tx, but I just discovered that the problem wasn't [], it was a bad (:not) selector that I added after :)

Answer (score 1):

```
If you wish to use any of the meta-characters 
( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a 
literal part of a name, you must escape the 
character with two backslashes: \\. 
For example, if you have an an element with 
id="foo.bar", you can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").
```

quoted from http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: tx. is there a function that can automatically escape a string? because that attribute is retrieved dynamically in my case.

Comment: @Alex, well, regex is the best approach... look at  qwertymk's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709986/jquery-select-a-element-by-the-name-attribute/4710011#4710011)

Comment: Instead of racing to the answer, let's race to close duplicate questions and help keep the clutter to a minimum :p

Answer (score 1):

First try using *double quotes* within the attribute selector:

```
$('*[name="'+thename+'"]').each()...
```

If that doesn't work, you can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, taking advantage of direct DOM access:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return this.name == thename;
})...
```