# jQuery get object by name when name contains a "["-character

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider this HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="inputa[42]" value="2012-05-02" />
<input type="text" name="inputb[42]" value="74,178" />

<input type="text" name="inputa[85]" value="2013-02-14" />
<input type="text" name="inputb[85]" value="21,35" />
```

How to use a jQuery selector to get the value of the input with name `inputa[85]`?

It would have been very easy if the name wouldn't have contained `[85]`, but now I can't get `$("input[name=inputa[85]]")` to work which is understandable, but how to solve it (without changing the name attribute)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)

Comment: Sorry, tried to find the answer to this already but I couldn't :) I should have searched for "brackets"!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In quotes:

```
$("input[name='inputa[85]']")
```

or

```
$('input[name="inputa[85]"]')
```

Comment: or `$("input[name=\"inputa[85]\"]")` :)

Comment: that is, as I wrote, in quotes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('input[name*="inputa"]')` if you don't know the value in brackets or abuduba's answer above.