# Sending value to form field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to send a value to the form field with the jQuery. Here's the basic code, it will work fine:

```
<input id="logo" name="logo" type="text" />
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#logo').val(imgurl);
```

However, I need to change the field ID to `option[logo]`. So I am trying this:

```
<input id="option[logo]" name="option[logo]" type="text" />
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#option[logo]').val(imgurl);
```

This does not work. How this can be fixed?

Comment: related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just use `[` or `]` literally as characters in an attribute/element name in a JQuery selector because they have a special meaning. You have to escape them. Read the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

This should work:

```
jQuery('#option\\[logo\\]').val(imgurl);
```

Comment: @user1355300 the pleasure is all mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

add a class  to that input and try with below

```
<input id="logo" class="option" name="option[logo]" type="text" />

jQuery('input.option').attr({
                             "id": "option\[logo\]",
                             "name": "option\[logo\]"
                            });
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht94P/)

Comment: $('input.option[id=logo]'); is cleaner

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the brackets in the jQuery like this:

```
$('#option\\[logo\\]').val(imgurl);
```