# jQuery input attribute change from x to y

Tags: jquery, types, attributes, ready

I try to replace the type of a input through jquery from "date_calendar" to "date". The input's name is "DateOfBirth[0]", but for some reason it doesn't work with the code bellow..

I am new to jquery/javascript and maybe I am missing something.. How can I do it? What did I missed?
This is the current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name=DateOfBirth[0]]').attr('type', 'date');
});
```

HTML:

```
<input min="1938-04-28" max="1995-04-28" class="form_input_date" type="date_calendar" name="DateOfBirth[0]">
```

Thank you very much..

Edit: I tried the double backslash `[name=DateOfBirth\\[0\\]]` and to quote the name value `[name="DateOfBirth[0]"]` but it still doesn't work..

Comment: show your HTML, or better still, make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
$('input[name="DateOfBirth[0]"]').attr('type', 'date');
```

- You need to double quotes the name here.
- Without quotes, you will get error like:

  - `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=DateOfBirth[0]]`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjzEw/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the type property of an input using jQuery, because IE doesn't support it.

[change type of input field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field)

You need to destroy the input and make a new one instead.