# Form validation not working on select drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have form with validations using Javascript. All of the drop downs are not validating. Any help?

```
<form id="itsp-form" method="post" action="http://www.url.com/save_itsp.php">
<label class="custom">Company name</label>
<input id="company_name" type="text" name="company_name" />

<label class="custom">Company URL</label>
<input id="company_url" type="text" name="company_url" />

<label class="custom">Company address</label>
<input id="company_address" type="text" name="company_address" />

<label class="custom">Type of business</label>
<select id="type_of_business[]" name="type_of_business[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="enterprise">Business sector/Enterprise</option>
  <option value="residential">Residential</option>
  <option value="wholesale">Wholesale VoIP Carrier</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<label class="custom">Areas served</label>
<select id="areas_served[]" name="areas_served[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<br />

<label class="custom">Sales contact</label><br />
<h4>Name</h4>
  <input id="sales_name" type="text" name="sales_name" />
<h4>Phone</h4>
  <input type="text" name="sales_phone" />
<h4>Email</h4>
  <input type="text" name="sales_email" />

<br />

<label class="custom">Testing contact</label><br />
<h4>Name</h4>
  <input id="testing_name" type="text" name="testing_name" />
<h4>Phone</h4>
  <input type="text" name="testing_phone" />
<h4>Email</h4>
  <input type="text" name="testing_email" />

<br />

<label class="custom">Switch Platform</label>
<select id="switch_platform[]" name="switch_platform[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="asterisk">Asterisk</option>
  <option value="broadsoft">Broadsoft</option>
  <option value="metaswitch">Metaswitch</option>
  <option value="sipx">SipX/eZuce</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<label class="custom">Interested In Testing</label>
<select id="interested_in_testing[]" name="interested_in_testing[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="atas">ATAs</option>
  <option value="ip_phones">IP Phones</option>
  <option value="gateways">Gateways</option>
  <option value="ip_pbx">IP PBX</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('.error').hide();

    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if (($("#company_name").val() == '') || ($("#type_of_business[]").val() == '')) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Company name.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if (($("#company_url").val() == '') || ($("#company_address").val() == '')) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Company information.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#areas_served[]").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Areas served.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#type_of_business[]").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Type of business.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#sales_name").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Sales contact information.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#testing_name").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Tester contact information</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#switch_platform[]").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Switch platform</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
    if ($("#interested_in_testing[]").val() == '') {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Testing interests.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
  if(hasError == true) { return false; }
});
```

Comment: I do not have any Javascript errors.

Comment: The arrays dont have a .val() I tried .length < 0

Comment: I also tried .length < 1. This did return an error but when I selected one the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your ids are using square brackets `[]` which in jquery is an attribute-equals-selector. See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

I would recommend not using square brackets in your id strings. Although permissible by html5, I would stick to using standard word and digit characters [a-zA-Z_0-9] to avoid issues with javascript tools and libraries

If you still want to use square brackets you must escape them. See [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<input type='submit'>`, the form will be submitted no matter what.
Try using `<input type='button'>` it may work then.

Comment: The problem is with the arrays. The .val() is not for an array.