# How to reference to element by name if name is array

Tags: jquery, html

So here is this element:

```
<TD><INPUT type="text" name="when"/></TD>
```

I can call a function by

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=when]').datepicker();
  });
```

This works fine.
(When I click the element, a datepicker shows up).

But what if this is the element?

```
<TD><INPUT type="text" name="when[]"/></TD>
```

Then this does not work:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=when[]]').datepicker();
  });
```

**EDIT:**

So thank you for answering me guys, I did not know this.
However. I let the users add rows to the table dynamically so each added row should inherit this function. Unfortunately it does not work in the dynamically created rows:

```
    function setClass() {
            $('input[name="when[]"]').datepicker();
//or $('input[name=when\\[\\]]').datepicker();
        }
```

Comment: Wrap the `when[]` part with quotes or escape it's  `[]` part.

Comment: @undefined: I wish I could upvote when people find the previous question. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder here you go :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha. Unfortunately there are many duplicates for most of the jQuery questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes:

```
$('input[name="when[]"]').datepicker();
```

In general, when an attribute value has anything in it but A-Z, put it in quotes.

Comment: Suggestion is to use quotes always not to confuse any time..

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder. Although this answers the question it does not always work. When I dynamically add rows to the table, then the datepicker does not show up, only on the first row which is created static. `function setClass() { $('input[name="when[]"]').datepicker();
 }`

Comment: @erdomester That's another problem? Ask different question.

Comment: I don't think that's exactly a different a question. If I asked that in a new post, then I would create almost another duplicate (just what I did)

Comment: Well it turned out to be a completely different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733530/unable-to-reference-to-dynamically-created-element-by-name#25733868