# Unable to reference to dynamically created element by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a table with one row when the page is created:

```
<TD><INPUT type="text" name="when"/></TD>
```

So when the user clicks on this element, a datepicker shows up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="when"]').datepicker();
});
```

When the user adds a new row to this table then I call the setClass function to set this on the new row (all rows):

```
function setClass() {
    $('[name="when"]').datepicker();
}
```

But this doesn't work on these dynamically created rows. Why?

This is how I add rows:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" class="add_remove_row" />

function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;


        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;

            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;

            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    setClass();
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas He's not binding an event, he's initializing a plugin, so delegation is not the answer.

Comment: @Barmar: good point, somehow I missed what was within the `setClass()` function >.<

Comment: This seems like a very un-jQuery-like way to add anew row to the table (as opposed to say cloning).  It would also seem that you may need to be more specific with your `setClass()` method to only target the input on the newly added row. Right now, you would try to initialize the datepicker on inputs that have already been initialized (not sure what behavior this might cause).

Comment: @MikeBrant It doesn't cause a problem, because datepicker remembers which elements it has already initialized, and doesn't reinitialize them.

Comment: Yes @Barmar, and that behavior is the heart of the issue! Beat you by 13 seconds!! :)

Comment: @LcSalazar I would have beat you by a couple minutes if I didn't also fix the ID problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Got it!!**

The problem is that when a Jquery's plugin `datepicker` is applied to an element, a class is set to the input called `hasDatepicker`.

When you call the plugin again, it checks first if the class already exists... If it does, than Jquery doesn't apply the datepicker, because it understands that it is already applied.

Since you are copying the `innerHTML` from the pre-existing cell:

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

you're copiyng the input with the class `hasDatepicker` already set on it. So Jquery won't implement the plugin.

A simple fix is to remove the class before the `datepicker` call:

```
var setClass = function() {
    $('[name="when"]').removeClass("hasDatepicker").datepicker();
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdzvr9km/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should just initialize the plugin on the newly-added elements. You need to take some special actions, though.

The datepicker plugin puts a class `hasDatepicker` on elements that it has already initialized, and doesn't re-initialize them. Since you're copying an element that has this class, you need to remove it so that it will be re-initialized. Second, if the element doesn't have an ID, datepicker adds a randomish ID to it. IDs need to be unique, but your code is copying the ID. In my code below, I simply remove the ID from the elements, so the plugin will add a new, unique one. If I didn't do this, the datepicker on a new row would fill in the first row (because it uses the ID internally when finding the input to update after you select something from the datepicker).

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[01].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;


        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;

            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;

            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    setClass(row);
}

function setClass(newrow) {
    $(newrow).find('.hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/94x2tyrz/7/)

Comment: Both solutions are good, but this seems stronger a bit. Thank you!