# Attribute name not recognized

Tags: jquery

```
<select name="search[quick_dates]" id="search_quick_dates">
...
</select>
```

and jQuery:

```
f.find('select[name=search[quick_dates]]').bind('change', { form: f }, function(e){
...
}
```

throws an error:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select[name=search[quick_dates]]`

Can I update my jQuery instead of changing the attribute name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use any of the meta-characters such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with backslashes:

Change it:

```
f.find('select[name=search[quick_dates]]')
```

To this:

```
f.find('select[name="search\\[quick_dates\\]"]')
```

Comment: Tried that already: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select[name=search\["quick_dates"\]]`

Comment: It is double, copy-pasted from here but chrome reports it that way (single backslashes)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape brackets. But using single backslashes will not escape brackets because single backslash will escape the character in the string inside the function but you need backslash to be part of the expression or selector and hence you will also have to escape backslash by another backslash.

Try this:

```
f.find('select[name=search\\[quick_dates\\]]')
```