# Submit value of a checkbox through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit values of a form through javascript it contains both text and two checkboxes.

```
<script>
  function SubmitFormData2() {
      var preffered_loc = $("#preffered_loc").val();
      var relocation = $(".relocation").val();
      $.post("r_two.php", { preffered_loc: preffered_loc,relocation: relocation },
      function(data) {
       $('#results').html(data);
       $('#myForm2')[0].reset();
      });
  }
</script>

<form id="myForm2" method="post" style="margin-left: -10%;">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="preffered_loc" name="preffered_loc">
   <input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" class="relocation[]" value="Yes">
   <input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" class="relocation[]" value="No" >
   <input type="button" id="submitFormData2" onclick="SubmitFormData2();" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**r_two.php**

```
<?
$preffered_loc  =  $_POST['preffered_loc'];
$relocation = $_POST['relocation'];
?>
```

i am able to save the first value but i am not able to save relocation value, can anyone tell how i can save relocation. Important point here is that user can select both checkboxes also

The issue is that $relocation is picking only value yes even if i select 2nd selectbox. can anyone please correct my code

Comment: There is no element with ID `relocation`You are using `id="relocation[]"` twice __Identifiers in HTML must be unique.__ , On second thought, Are you sure you want  `checkbox` for `Yes` and `No`?

Comment: As you are using id in selector it always returns first DOM object. You might wanna change your selector to class or something else

Comment: @Satpal yes i would like to use checkbox only however i can go for some other way to pass the value to php script

Comment: @Diljohn5741 i tried to change it to class but still not working

Comment: if its just and YES/NO option, should not be using radio button insted of check box?, also, if you want to use checkbox you should first check wich one is checked and then pass that value.

Comment: If you want to submit either of the values at one time try using radio button with same name attribute. Then check using below code

jQuery('input:radio:checked').val()

Comment: Use radio not checkbox, don't use [] in a css class, remove the [] from the name of the radio (again, this is not a checkbox scenario, style it if you want it to look that way), also where's your #results element?

Comment: And could I suggest binding your event with `$(document).on('click','#submitFormData2', function() {SubmitFormData();});` 
or similar rather than using an onclick declaration in the element?

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```js
function SubmitFormData2() {
        var preffered_loc = $("#preffered_loc").val();
        var relocation = $("#relocation").is(":checked");
        var relyn = "";
        if(relocation){
            relyn = "Yes";
        }else{
            relyn = "No";
        }
        $.post("r_two.php", { preffered_loc: preffered_loc,relocation: relyn },
        function(data) {
           $('#results').html(data);
           $('#myForm2')[0].reset();
        });
        alert("{ preffered_loc: "+preffered_loc+",relocation: "+relyn+" }");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm2" method="post" style="margin-left: -10%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="preffered_loc" name="preffered_loc">
        <input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" id="relocation" /> 
        <input type="button" id="submitFormData2" onclick="SubmitFormData2();" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

As Satpal said:

- You don't need two checkbox, maybe you want a radio button, but one checkbox can be checked = yes, not checked = no. I removed one of them.
- You don't have an ID relocation. I changed it.
- With the jQuery is(":checked") you get a true or false so I parse it to a Yes or No, following your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since its a checkbox and not a radio user can have multiple selections, for eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" class="relocation" value="Yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" class="relocation" value="No" >
<input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" class="relocation" value="Both" >
```

try using the `:checked` selector,

```
$( ".relocation:checked" ).each(function(i,v){
   alert(v.value)
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/z3kag9rm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't select the checkbox elements at all because you weren't including the `[]` in the selector. You can either escape the brackets as described in [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute) or simply remove the brackets (the example code below does the latter)

I'd suggest using radio buttons as the user can immediately see what the options are. (Have a third option for both)

The code below uses checkboxes and puts all selected options into an array that gets passed along. This will allow the user to use both options

```
<script>
  function SubmitFormData2() {
      var preffered_loc = $("#preffered_loc").val();
      var relocation = [];
     $(".relocation:checked").each(function () {
        relocation.push ($this.vak ();
     }); // :checked is provided by jquery and will only select a checkbox/radio button that is checked
      $.post("r_two.php", { preffered_loc: preffered_loc,relocation: relocation },
      function(data) {
       $('#results').html(data);
       $('#myForm2')[0].reset();
      });
  }
```

And don't forget to remove `[]` from the checkboxes class.

Comment: Question was not for radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use class for the check-boxes instead of id, because id must be unique for each field. You should try this:

```
 <form id="myForm2" method="post" style="margin-left: -10%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="preffered_loc" name="preffered_loc">
        <input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" class="relocation" value="Yes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="relocation[]" class="relocation" value="No" > 
        <input type="button" id="submitFormData2" onclick="SubmitFormData2();" value="Submit" />
    </form> 

   <script>
    function SubmitFormData2() {
        var preffered_loc = $("#preffered_loc").val();
    var relocation = '';
    var sap = '';
    $( ".relocation" ).each(function() {

        if($( this ).is(':checked')){
            relocation = relocation+''+sap+''+$( this ).val();
            sap = ',';
        }
    });
        alert(rel);
        $.post("r_two.php", { preffered_loc: preffered_loc,relocation: relocation },
        function(data) {
         $('#results').html(data);
         $('#myForm2')[0].reset();
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for your reference

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
     Name:    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br />
     Email:   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
     Phone No:<input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" /><br />
     Gender:  <input name="gender" type="radio" value="male">Male
          <input name="gender" type="radio" value="female">Female<br />

    <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
   </form>

function SubmitFormData() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var gender = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    $.post("submit.php", { name: name, email: email, phone: phone, gender: gender },
    function(data) {
     $('#results').html(data);
     $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        function SubmitFormData2() {
            var preffered_loc   = $("#preffered_loc").val();
            var relocation      = {};

            $('.relocation').each(function(index) {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    relocation[index] = $(this).val();
                }
            });

            relocation = JSON.stringify(relocation);

            $.post("r_two.php", { preffered_loc: preffered_loc, relocation: relocation }, function(data) {
               $('#results').html(data);
               $('#myForm2')[0].reset();              
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Variable 'relocation' must be an object to contain multiple values, like you said a user can select both YES and NO. And change the checkbox class from relocation[] to relocation.