# How do I update the jQuery find selector if I make the input form field name an array?

Tags: jquery

I'm repurposing some code to dynamically add form fields.  So I had this:

```
<input name="projDesc" />
```

and used the following to create additional fields:

```
function GetHtml() {

    var len = $('.extraProject').length;
    var $html = $('.extraProjectTemplate').clone();

    $html.find('[name=projDesc]')[0].name="projDesc" + len;

    return $html.html();
```

}

But now I need to switch the input to an array for PHP to process it:

```
<input name="projDesc[]" />
```

How do I change the .find method to accommodate this now?  Thx.

Followup:

Sorry for the dupe but what are some possible reasons it works in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pjoh2tg/) but not on my site?  On my site now, I don't even get the initial form field to display.

Also do I need to escape the square brackets in both instances where I mention projDesc?

```
$html.find('[name=projDesc\\[\\]]')[0].name="projDesc\\[\\]" + len;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the selector:

```
...
$html.find('[name=projDesc\\[\\]]')[0].name = 'projDesc' + len;
...
```

Answer lies here: [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute)