# jquery can't seem to select dom element inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I came across a problem while trying to select a DOM element inside a callback function using Jquery, I always get undefined value, note that there is nothing wrong with the key variable, the only problem is that Jquery can't seem to select the input element and get its value.

```
 $(".mybutton").on('click', function(){
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     __CANVAS.mousemove(function(evt){
       var mousePos = getMousePos(__CANVAS2, evt);
       $("#x[" + key + "]").val(); // undefined
       $("#y[" + key + "]").val(); // undefined
   });
});
```

This is the html

```
 <input id="x['.$key.']" name="x'.$key.'" type="text"  value="x'.$key.'" width="50px">
                                     x
 <input id="y['.$key.']" name="y'.$key.'" type="text"  value="y'.$key.'" width="50px">
                                     y
 <button type="button" key="'.$key.'" class="mybutton">Create/Edit</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a valid `id` attribute (brackets aren't allowed). spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/types.html#type-name Additionally, brackets are special characters in jQuery selectors so your selector is not being treated a literal string. You may be able to escape the brackets so the string is treated literally though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute

Comment: As a side note: it is a bad idea to attach an event listener inside a click handler, as you will accumulate event handlers.

Comment: @RobM. HTML5 has relaxed the character restrictions on IDs.

Comment: When you `console.log(key)` after assigning it's value to `$(this).attr('key')`, what do you get?

Comment: Rob M. I changed the id to `id="x'.$key.'"` but still have the same problem undefined,

Comment: trincot I delete the event listener after the user clicks on the canvas

Comment: wlh with every input I get the its key number, there's nothing wrong with it.