# How to access input type name as JobRoles[1].BasedIn in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields with names *`"JobRoles[0].AgeFrom"`* and *`"JobRoles[1].AgeFrom"`*. How can I access *`"JobRoles[0].AgeFrom"`* through jquery

I tried to access the field like this

```
 $(options.form).find(':input[name=' + fullOtherName + ']')[0];
```

but it show unrecognized expression: `:input[name=JobRoles[0].AgeFrom]`

Comment: Wrap the name in quotes `[name="' + fullOtherName + '"]`

Comment: I thhink this also due to the `:` before the input :)

Comment: @bRIMOs Nope. Check my answer below. There is [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector in jQuery.

Comment: @Tushar ah yep great :)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2365001/2025923) answer. Wrap the name of element in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your variable inside `"`. it will work.

```
var fullOtherName = 'JobRoles[0].AgeFrom';

alert($(document).find('input[name="' + fullOtherName + '"]').val());
```

```js
var fullOtherName = 'JobRoles[0].AgeFrom';

alert($(document).find('input[name="' + fullOtherName + '"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="JobRoles[0].AgeFrom" value="123" />
```

Comment: yes, its works fine thank U @Amit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) on the input name field

like `$("input[name*='AgeFrom']"` and access the first element ([0])

See below snippet :

```js
$(function(){
  var fullOtherName = 'AgeFrom';
  console.log($("input[name*='AgeFrom']"));
  alert($("input[name*='"+fullOtherName+"']")[0].value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="JobRoles[0].AgeFrom" value="0"/>
<input name="JobRoles[1].AgeFrom" value="1"/>
```