# how to capture when a checked checkbox becomes unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I want to get the value of the checkbox that goes from being checked to unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cbx" name="privilegiosG[]" id="privilegioG_<?= $privilegio->getId() ?>" value="<?= $privilegio->getId() ?>" <?= $checked; ?> />
```

tried this but it doesn't work for me

```
<script type="text/javascript>"

    $("input[name='seccionesG'] input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var ischecked= $(this).is(":checked");
    if(!ischecked)
        alert("uncheckd " + $(this).val());
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I can't quite tell - because everything is surrounded with back-ticks, so this may be a template-literal? - but it seems like you're trying to use `"` characters inside of a string delimited with the same `"` characters: `$("input[name="seccionesG"] input:checkbox")`; this won't work unless you escape the inner pair: `$("input[name=\"seccionesG\"] input:checkbox")` or - preferably - use different quotes on the outer, and inner, strings.

Comment: yes I just saw it but even when adjusted it is still not working

Comment: Where does it fail, what - if any - errors are reported? What's the HTML that your browser sees, and works with? (It definitely *shouldn't* include any php, which is almost certainly irrelevant to the problem.) It's worth pointing out the obvious issue that the `name` of the `<input>` you show does not match the `name` you quote in your jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks quite complicated for a simple task, this should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check_state(this);">

<script type="text/javascript">

  function check_state(checkbox)
  {
    var val = checkbox.value;
    if(checkbox.checked)
    {
      //is checked
    }
    else
    {
      //is not checked
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of incorrect selector: `input[name='seccionesG'] input:checkbox`.

It's invalid, it's means: find an input with name `seccionesG`, then inside it look for all inputs which are checkboxes.

You can test it quickly by making a selector which will work for all checkboxes:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() { 
    console.log(this.name, this.checked); 
});
```

Now, since your input name is `privilegiosG[]` then your selector should be:

```
$('input[name="privilegiosG[]"]').change(function() { 
    console.log(this.name, this.checked); 
});
```

Note that you have a name with square brackets, which has a special meaning. For this reason you will need to add quotes to make it work. If you want to know more check [jQuery selector for inputs with square brackets in the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364982/jquery-selector-for-inputs-with-square-brackets-in-the-name-attribute).